# How can i wrap a special kind of string pattern inside parentheses ()

Tags: php, regex

I have a code like this

```
$firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
$lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
```

and many other variables. I want to replace all $_POST['something'] to mysqli_real_string_escape($conn,$_POST['something']) inside the code in all files.

```
$firstname=mysqli_real_string_escape($conn,$_POST['first_name']);
$lastname=mysqli_real_string_escape($conn,$_POST['last_name']);
```

How can i do this?

Comment: This question seems more related to some feature of replacing a text by another in the IDE than some programming issue. Looking to the slice of code that you have shared, you may have some issues if the $conn var does not exist in all the places where you are calling/replacing.

Comment: You should be using a prepared statement rather than escaping input. Doing so will make your life easier, and your code safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/TEvfW7/1)

You may Try this:

```
\$_POST\['([^']*)'\]
```

and Replace by this:

```
mysqli_real_string_escape($conn,$_POST['\1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop :

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $val) { 
  $_POST[$name] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $val);
}
```